# Python Pyrad dictionary error

Tags: python, radius

I setup some RADIUS backend to allow AD authentication via the 'admin' of django. Alltough i got a problem with some dictionaries, i really don't know what i'm doing wrong. This is the error i got:

IOError at /admin/
**Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pl/dictionary.compat'**

I installed pyrad, so it should be there and i've got a 'dic't file in the following style (/home/pl/dict):

```
#
# Version $Id: dictionary,v 1.1.1.1 2002/10/11 12:25:39 wichert Exp $
.....
$INCLUDE dictionary.compat # compability issues
$INCLUDE dictionary.acc
$INCLUDE dictionary.ascend
$INCLUDE dictionary.bay
....
```

The code i use in the RADIUS backend:

```
srv = Client(server=settings.RADIUS_SERVER,
      secret=settings.RADIUS_SECRET,
      dict=Dictionary("/home/pl/dict"))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The $INCLUDE directive in the configuration files is intended to add definitions from another dictionary file. Unless the extra dictionary files are found, the dictionary object cannot be created.

My advice is:
- if you don't have the extra dictionary files: comment out/remove the $INCLUDE lines 
- if you have the extra dictionary files: copy them to the right location

Comment: Where can i get the dictionary files and where are they located?

Comment: In the pyrad source distribution you may find, aside from the diccionary file that you're using, another one called diccionary.attingo. Unfortunately, there are no other configuration files.

Comment: Anyway, please note that the way it works is that you should know beforehand which vendor-specific AVPs (the ones in the RFCs are already included) would you like to decode and get the file from the vendor or create your own file based on the vendor specification.